# how to use arraylist.get() without typecasting arraylist

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, methods

I am currently making a program that has a method that needs to return multiple things of different types, so i am trying to use an ArrayList. The ArrayList doe not have a specific type so it can hold multiple, and after the method runs, should always have an array of ints in the 0 index.

```
ret = dealCards(ret, deck, dtotal, ptotal, dhand, phand);
    deck = ret.get((Integer[])0);
```

how do i typecast it to properly return me an array of integers?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java: Bounded heterogeneous collections when items are not related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176140/java-bounded-heterogeneous-collections-when-items-are-not-related)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a raw type and why shouldn't we use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it)

Comment: You should not ever return multiple items of different types. Create a wrapper class for return values or use functional approach and pass a function as an argument

Answer (score 0):

Oops! Figured it about after playing with it for a little more. I changed it to:

```
deck = (int[])ret.get(0);
```